# Async RabbitMQ communcation using Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-amqp

I have two spring boot services that communicate using RabbitMQ.
Service1 sends request for session creation to Service2.
Service2 handles request and should return response.
Service1 should handle the response.

Service1 method for requesting session:

```
public void startSession()
{
     ListenableFuture<SessionCreationResponseDTO> sessionCreationResponse = sessionGateway.requestNewSession();

     sessionCreationResponse.addCallback(response -> {
             //handle success
     }, ex -> {
            // handle exception
     });
}
```

On Service1 I have defined AsyncOutboundGateway, like:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow requestSessionFlow(MessageChannel requestNewSessionChannel, 
                                          AsyncRabbitTemplate amqpTemplate,
                                          SessionProperties sessionProperties)
{
        return flow -> flow.channel(requestNewSessionChannel)
                .handle(Amqp.asyncOutboundGateway(amqpTemplate)
                        .exchangeName(sessionProperties.getRequestSession().getExchangeName())
                        .routingKey(sessionProperties.getRequestSession().getRoutingKey()));
    }
```

On Service2, I have flow for receiving these messages:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow requestNewSessionFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, 
                                             SessionProperties sessionProperties,
                                             MessageConverter messageConverter, 
                                             RequestNewSessionHandler requestNewSessionHandler)
{
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundGateway(connectionFactory, 
                                sessionProperties.requestSessionProperties().queueName())
                .handle(requestNewSessionHandler)
                .get();
```

Service2 handles there requests:

```
@ServiceActivator(async = "true")
public ListenableFuture<SessionCreationResponseDTO> handleRequestNewSession()
{
    SettableListenableFuture<SessionCreationResponseDTO> settableListenableFuture = new SettableListenableFuture<>();

       // Goes through asynchronous process of creating session and sets value in listenable future

    return settableListenableFuture;
}
```

Problem is that Service2 immediately returns ListenableFuture to Service1 as message payload, instead of waiting for result of future and sending back result.

If I understood documentation correctly [Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/service-activator.html#async-service-activator) by setting async parameter in `@ServiceActivator` to true, successful result should be returned and in case of exception, error channel would be used.

Probably I misunderstood documentation, so that I need to unpack ListenableFuture in flow of Service2 before returning it as response, but I am not sure how to achieve that.

I tried something with `publishSubscribeChannel` but without much luck.

Comment: Any chances to see a simple project from you to play with? And what is your `sessionGateway` definition? I don't think the problem is with the `Service2`. That `async = "true"` should do the trick and `Amqp.inboundGateway()` must return the proper value. The `Amqp.asyncOutboundGateway()` does not return immediately. It does that `future.addCallback(new FutureCallback(requestMessage, correlationData));` on demand of the `Future`. The gateway configuration might be a bit wrong. See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#async-gateway

Comment: Hi, here is the simple project
https://github.com/borist2/spring-integration-async-test

I also tried defining asyncExecutor on SessionGateway, but without luck.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
.handle(requestNewSessionHandler)
```

Such a configuration doesn't see your `@ServiceActivator(async = "true")` and uses it as a regular blocking service-activator.

Let's see if this helps you:

```
.handle(requestNewSessionHandler, "handleRequestNewSession", e -> e.async(true))
```

It is better to think about it like: or only annotation configuration. or only programmatic, via Java DSL.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you very much. Documentation even mentioned that, but I did not found how it fitted. If I can as, a follow up question. Only annotation configuration would work when XML configuration is used? Or when when components are related using explicit channel names?

Comment: Yes, only when it is true endpoint: comes with an `inputChannel` attribute